# Quickblox webRTC was built for newer iOS versions (9.0) than being linked to (7.1)

Tags: ios, linker, webrtc, quickblox

I am creating an video calling app and integrated Quickblox WebRTC framework.My application Minimum deployment target is 7.1.I was getting the mentioned warning and i know that, the library is officially supports from Deployment Target 9.0.These are my concerns on this below.

1. As these are just warnings, can i just ignore and continue with my app minimum deployment target 7.1
2. What problems will it create at run time when this library is running on lower versions like iOS 7.1 till iOS 9.
3. Will Apple reject apps in review if libraries are linked to lower targets.
4. If i need to avoid linking this to iOS 7.0 then is there any solution in Quickblox that supports Video calling from iOS 7.1 to recent versions.

Please suggest me regarding solving this issue. My app minimum deployment must be iOS 7.1 and higher.

proven and acceptable solutions will be appreciated and up voted.

Answer (score 1):

1. YES
2. No problems
3. NO
4. Quickblox supports Video calling from iOS 7.0

Please refer to [this sample video project](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios).

Comment: Thank you.I would be just ignoring the warnings and continue with my 7.1 minimum deployment target.

Comment: @ V.Guru, can you just go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807922/symbol-not-found-kvtdecompressionpropertykey-realtime