# Symbol not found: _kVTDecompressionPropertyKey_RealTime

Tags: ios, crash, webrtc, quickblox

I am getting crash at launch time, with the following terms in the

console.

dyld: Symbol not found: _kVTDecompressionPropertyKey_RealTime

Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/25A09982-788D-4847-93D9-C6420B0B5628/Makeit.app/Makeit

Expectedin:/System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
 in /var/mobile/Applications/25A09982-788D-4847-93D9C6420B0B5628/Makeit.app/Makeit

can any one tell how to fix this. I already checked for VideoToolbox framework, its added in my project also.

my only suspect is, in my app i am using Quickblox WebRTC framework which is to be linked for iOS 9.0 but my app deployment target is 7.1.Is this any problem for this kind of error.Suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

VideoToolbox is only available from iOS 8+. You can set it to optional: click on it in project navigator, in the right panel, where Target membership is, select Optional instead of required.

Please keep in mind that you will not be able to use h264 codec from now on.

Comment: will Video conference can still work on iOS 7 series OS when we set it optional? By the way what is h264 codec and would it be completely unused in the project if i set that Framework optional?what benefits will i lose from doing so?

Comment: You cannot use that codec because it requires iOS8+. Yes, video conference will still work.

Comment: Last concern on this.Can i use that service in iOS 8 and higher by checking the API Availability.Because iOS 8 and higher devices will be having that VideoTool Frame work so can i make use of that in that cases?

Comment: also can you please go through this with your goodness http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855064/retrieve-records-from-quickblox-api

Comment: You can use it on iOS8+. Thats why you are setting framework as optional.