# Retrieve Records from Quickblox API

Tags: quickblox, relation, custom-object

I am using Quickblox SDK in my Application and designed Custom Objects in the Quickblox Admin panel.Here i am having some complex relationship between Custom Objects and not able to figure out how to retrieve the records using the Quickblox API.

Problem:

There are two tables 1.User 2.Group, i am successfully fetching all the groups created by a specific using by using parent_id key as mention in Quickblox API for maintaining relationships between tables.

I want to retrieve all the groups created by the user and also the groups in which the user is added as a member which are created by other Users.How can i solve this? In my group table i am having a column that is an array of userIds to represent all the group members.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this.How i can query and retrieve.I am really poor at DB  knowledge and moreover Quickblox is a having different approach in the DB Design.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to solve this.Any suggestions relating solving would be appreciated

Comment: Here are some links that may help you: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios and http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];    
[getRequest setObject:user_id forKey:@“user_ids_column_name[in]"];
[getRequest setObject:user_id forKey:@"ParentID"];


    QBRequestErrorBlock errorBlock = ^(QBResponse *response) {

        NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);

    };

    [QBRequest objectsWithClassName:@“Group” extendedRequest:getRequest successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *objects, QBResponsePage *page){


        NSLog(@"Success");


    } errorBlock:errorBlock];
```